# Creating a Docker container using Github actions does not update package in github packages

Tags: docker, github-actions, digital-ocean

The following .github workflow script does not update the packages ones deployed on Github packages.

After every deployment, I would like the script to update the packages deployed.

Here is my deploy script. Can someone please let me know how to modify it so a new package is created after every deploy?

```
name: Continuous Integration and Delivery

on: [ push ]

env:
  WEB_IMAGE: ghcr.io/$(echo $GITHUB_REPOSITORY | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]')/web
  NGINX_IMAGE: ghcr.io/$(echo $GITHUB_REPOSITORY | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]')/nginx

jobs:

  build:
    name: Build Docker Images
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Log in to GitHub Packages
        run: echo ${PERSONAL_ACCESS_TOKEN} | docker login ghcr.io -u ${{ secrets.NAMESPACE }} --password-stdin
        env:
          PERSONAL_ACCESS_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.PERSONAL_ACCESS_TOKEN }}
      - name: Build images
        run: |
          docker-compose down -v
          docker-compose -f docker-compose.ci.yml build
      - name: Push images
        run: |
          docker push ${{ env.WEB_IMAGE }}
          docker push ${{ env.NGINX_IMAGE }}
```

The github package only stays at the original time the initial push was and does not update the package. And upon inspecting, the code change is the original one and does not change to the new one.

[image]

On github actions, it shows that it has been successfully pushed

[image]

Here is docker.ci

```
version: "3.8"

services:
  web:
    build:
      context: ./app
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.prod
    image: "${WEB_IMAGE}"
    command: gunicorn hello_django.wsgi:application --bind 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - static_volume:/usr/src/app/staticfiles
      - media_volume:/usr/src/app/mediafiles
    expose:
      - 8000
    env_file: .env
  nginx:
    build:
      context: ./nginx
    image: "${NGINX_IMAGE}"
    volumes:
      - static_volume:/usr/src/app/staticfiles
      - media_volume:/usr/src/app/mediafiles
    ports:
      - 80:80
    depends_on:
      - web

volumes:
  static_volume:
  media_volume:
```

Comment: What do you mean by "code changes are detected"? Your action runs when you push a commit, right? Local changes cannot be detected since they are local; or am I missing something?

Comment: @Rafael-WO `docker-compose -f docker-compose.ci.yml build` this line is suppose to wrap the code changes so it is deployed

Comment: Ok, but what's the concrete issue? Does it refuse to build?

Comment: @Rafael-WO I narrowed down the problem now, the github packages is not updating.

Comment: But that's weird, it should be updating it. Sorry if I cannot help you further...

Comment: Could you include the logs from you actions where the images are being pushed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was the docker tag was not included on the push. I added the tags on the push and it was fixed.

The following is **NOT** enough, you must also add the tag to the push or else github repository will not update it for some reason.

```
  - name: Push images
    run: |
      docker push ${{ env.WEB_IMAGE }}
      docker push ${{ env.NGINX_IMAGE }}
```

You have to do the following

```
  - name: Push images
    run: |
      docker tag ${{ env.WEB_IMAGE }}  ${{ env.WEB_IMAGE_BASE }}:latest
      docker push ${{ env.WEB_IMAGE }}
      docker push ${{ env.WEB_IMAGE_BASE }}:latest
      docker tag ${{ env.NGINX_IMAGE }} ${{ env.NGINX_IMAGE_BASE }}:latest
      docker push ${{ env.NGINX_IMAGE }}
      docker push ${{ env.NGINX_IMAGE_BASE }}:latest
```